# SonarQube states "lines not covered" but they are covered by UnitTests (MediatR Handle)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sonarqube, mediatr, mediator

I'm facing a problem with SonarQube and I think it has to do with the Handle function of MediatR in C#.

Here is the handle function which SonarQube says is not covered by tests
[image]

But this function is tested by these two unit tests:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task SpeichereBetriebCommandHandler_SollteGuidZurueckgeben_WennBetriebNichtExistiert()
{
    // Arrange
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();

    var speichereBetriebCommand = fixture.Build<SpeichereBetriebCommand>().Create();
    
    // Act
    var result = await _speichereBetriebCommandHandler.Handle(speichereBetriebCommand, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
    
    // Assert
    result.Should().NotBe(String.Empty);
}

[Fact]
public async Task SpeichereBetriebCommandHandler_SollteLeerStringZurueckgeben_WennBetriebExistiert()
{
    // Arrange
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();

    var someData .....

    var betrieb = fixture.Build<BetriebDto>()
        .With(b => b.SomeData, someData )
        .
        .
        .
        .Create();

    var speichereBetriebCommand = fixture.Build<SpeichereBetriebCommand>()
        .With(b => b.SomeData, someData)
        .
        .
        .
        .Create();
    
    await _betriebRepository.AddAsync(betrieb);
    await _statistikContextRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    // Act
    var result = await _speichereBetriebCommandHandler.Handle(speichereBetriebCommand, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
    
    // Assert
    result.Should().Be(String.Empty);
}
```

I've also debugged the unit tests and both land in the handle function. So I've tested the complete function. Why does SonarQube not agree with me?

Comment: Is SonarCube looking at a "Release" build? So source might not match IL?

Comment: SonarQube is looking at the development branch for a merge request. This is all fine

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. The root cause was that I was utilizing XUnit, but there were still some NUnit references present in my .csproj file. This caused the tests to not execute properly in the pipeline.